# Objective-C delegate function not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have an app that has three views. All three views have an Ad Banner at the bottom of the screen. The first view creates an audio streamer which is paused when the Ad Banner on this view is clicked. I'm trying to use the AdBanner delegate methods on the second view to stop/start the audio. When the Ad Banner is selected the AdBanner delegate methods should call my custom delegate functions. The code compiles and runs but doesn't function correctly.

Using NSLog I've determined that the Ad Banner is calling its delegate function correctly but this isn't calling the custom delegate.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

SecondViewControler H-file

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@protocol demoViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required

-(void)stopSent;
-(void)startSent;

@end

@interface SecondViewController ()
{    
    id<demoViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}    
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<demoViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

SecondViewController M-file

```
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize delegate;
```

Protocols

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    [delegate stopSent];
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
[delegate startSent];
}
```

FirstViewController H-file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "iAd/iAd.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "AudioStreamer.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "MFAppDelegate.h"
#import "MFSideMenu.h"

Class secondViewConroller;

@interface DemoViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate,demoViewControllerDelegate> {
}

@end
```

FirstViewController M-file

```
-(void)stopSent{
    if (isPlaying) {
        [streamer stop];
        wasPlaying=true;
    }
}

-(void)startSent{
    if (wasPlaying) {
        [streamer start];
         isPlaying=true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where are those delegate methods actually defined?  "`demoViewControllerDelegate`" or "`ADBannerViewDelegate`"? Your .h files don't say.

Comment: The AdBannerViewDelegate functions are just the standard Xcode implementations.

Comment: I've amended the original post to add the code I left out.

Comment: Unrelated to Xcode. Retagged.

Comment: Did you check if the delegate is not nil in the `bannerViewActionShouldBegin` and `bannerViewActionDidFinish` method?

Comment: I just tested using if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendStop:) ] ) { } with an NSLog inside and there was no log displayed. Does this mean the delegate is Nil?

Comment: Where is your delegate property declaration?

Comment: Sorry, left some code out of my original post. I've amended it now.

Comment: If your if statement didnt log the stament then delegate is probably nil. I dont see any code setting the delegate.
A simple way to output this is NSLog(@"delegate is nil?:%@", delegate ? @"NO" : @"YES");  its probably nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protocol methods need to be implemented in the class that you've designated as your delegate target.

It looks like your DemoViewController (or FirstViewController) is the object you've designated as the delegate, since you've given the interface the "`<ADBannerViewDelegate,demoViewControllerDelegate>`" designations.

Then, from your Second View Controller, you can call the object you designated and set as a delegate by doing:

```
[delegate startSent];
```

and

```
[delegate stopSent];
```

in the appropriate locations, which appear to be "`bannerViewActionShouldBegin`" and "`bannerViewActionDidFinish`", respectively.

You should also make sure that the delegate is properly set, therefore instead of:

```
[delegate startSent];
```

you should **actually** do this:

```
if(delegate)
    [delegate startSent];
else
    NSLog( @"delegate is null; we should figure out why" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tested your suggestion and I was given a warning saying that the instance method was not found.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that the delegate is Null.